# Apache Airflow - user mangement and multi-tenancy

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to create a single Apache Airflow instance that can host multiple users, that will be unable to affect one another negatively. This would include but not limited to:

- Maintain their own python environments
- Manage their own variables
- Manage their own connections
- Manage their own dags

Looking through the official airflow docs. I see a couple things that may help.

1) ability to create users and 2) the ability to be multi tenant.

1) If I follow the user creation process https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#web-authentication. All the users created seem to be admin, but how do I create a non admin user and control what can they do / not do? I can't seem to locate anymore documentation.

2) The link, https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#multi-tenancy, says that "You can filter the list of dags in webserver by owner name when authentication is turned on by setting ", but I don't see how I can assign dags to specific users.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* that user management doesn't work like that in Airflow but haven't worked in depth with that.

To 1: As far as I understand there are no in-build roles in Airflow. User management is firstly about authentication and access to Airflow. If needed, you might need to implement a few Flask hooks as described here: https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#roll-your-own

To 2: When creating a DAG, you set it's ownership with the

```
default_args = {
     owner: 'my_owner_name',
     ...
```

string parameter. This seems to be the part which binds DAGs to user authentication. So the user with the handle `my_owner_name` could list the above DAG.

Comment: Tobi Can you explain exact steps you followed to get it working .It will be a great help for all airflow users.

Comment: Sorry, haven't used it yet, because of that the 'think'.

Comment: I tried the same things and changed airflow.cfg accordingly but no luck.But this supposed to be nice feature so that same airflow instance we can share across multiple teams with maintenance overhead of only one cluster